# create droplet app. to transform xml with xslt

Tags: xslt, saxon

I want to create a application, where you drop a xml doc on it, and  an xslt transformation occurs using saxon as the transform engine. The result is a text file.
I am doing this on a mac. Does anyone know where I could find a beginner tutorail to approach this??
Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

At [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/), take a look at the [saxon resource zip file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.2/saxon-resources9-2-0-2.zip/download), it contains example applications for saxon.